# How to get url of object in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've got a `Product` model.

How do I get the url of a product in Rails 3, in a controller.

For example (pseudo code):

```
def foobar
  @product = Product.first
  puts @product.url
end
```

Is such a thing possible?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Assuming the `Product` model is mapped as :resources in your `routes.rb` file:

```
def foobar
  @product = Product.first
  url = product_url(@product)
end
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer, just a note ```product_path``` is useful if you don't want the full url returned.

Comment: ...and ```polymorphic_path``` if you want to DRY things up in a helper - See [PolymorphicRoutes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/PolymorphicRoutes.html)

Answer (score 21):

In addition to named route `product_url(@product)` you can use the general `url_for(@product)` ([docs](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/url_for)). This has a side effect that if you have nested or namespaced routes, it is shorter:

```
customer_product_url(@customer, @product)
url_for([@customer, @product])
```

Also note, that by default `url_for` produces *relative* URLs, just as `product_path` would, which depending on your needs might be good or bad. To get full URL, pass `:only_path => false`.

Comment: `url_for` can also produce namespaced urls. To achieve this, do something like `url_for([:namespace, @product])`.